# iOS: Which flag in Xcode will declare my app for both iPhone and iPad?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have developed an educational app, and have built it with a storyboard of iPhone. It is working perfectly on iPad without a need for a change (except for pressing the 'X2' button).

Now that the app is active in App Store, I see that iPad users who search for my keywords, do not receive my app in their search results, unless changing the top menu from 'iPad Only' to 'iPhone Only'.

I am wondering if there is a flag that will set my app to appear in the search results for iPad users too.

Or am I forced to create another storyboard?

Will appreciate you help!!

Comment: Your negative rating is not justified! True that you can set a target to **universal**, but there is still a flag behind, which is **Targeted Device Family**, and it can be set in project level to affect all targets at once. The question came from someone who worked _hard_ on a project for more than two years, just to find out that iPad users will not find his app in their searches, just because of a tiny change in the App Store app which used to show both iPad and iPhone apps in two sections of the search results, and now show you only iPad, unless you select 'iPhone Only' at the top

Answer (score 2):

There is no flag for that.

You can create a Universal App (meaning you do support both iPhone and iPad) which then will mean your app is listed in both iPhone and iPad searches on the App Store, **however** you need to also provide a UI for the iPad version too in this case!

Comment: Please see my answer. I know that you can create a new universal app. The question was how to fix an existing app!

Comment: Like I said, you make it universal. Select your Application Target, then in the Deployment Info, you change the Devices to Universal

Comment: Hi @Lefteris. please see my comment in response to the question

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to be: Targeted Device Family

When setting it for both iPhone and iPad, a different UI will be presented for iPad, and you should adapt it to appear correctly.

EDIT

As mentioned by @Lefteris, each target can be marked as *universal* for that same purpose, but Targeted Device Family exists in the **project** level and allows setting that flag **for all target at once**.

I'm still missing a practical guide for turning an iPhone app into universal: how to add a storyboard and how to turn a two-levels behavior (table -> data) into a split table view.